# akka persistence deleting journal entries

Tags: akka, persistence, event-sourcing

We're building an event sourced application using akka persistence and we have a requirement to destroy records after a given period of time, 7 years in this case. I understand that I could probably just delete up until the closest snapshot to a time boundary for a given persistence id assuming snapshotting is used but I'd like to see how others have approached this issue.